Wave function collapse at particle detection
There is a particle source, which emits particles (e.g. radioactive decay). It is supposed that the wave function is spherical. The process is isotropic. If I put two detectors (A and B) at distance R from the source, I could count the particles detected. Let's suppose that the number of particles detected is 5012 and 4956 for detector A and B, respectively, within a time interval.
If detector A is removed from the setup, is it true that detector B would count roughly double number of particles, approximately 10000 within the same time interval?
The wave function is collapsing every time one particle is detected. If one detector is removed, the other one should detect those particles.

Have you considered 267 detectors? They only cover specific solid angles of estimation of a probability distribution.

Cosmas Zachos: Have you heard about the article(s) of Einstein and Podolsky? Many idiots downvoted my question.

You are covering entangled pairs in your question? Clarify. What confuses said idiots?

In vacuum emitted particles are non localized. Their wave functions spread out and could reach different detectors.

A spherical wave for one particle. How did you slip EPR there? Where is the entanglement?

If the wave is spherical, things happen as I described in the opening question. So, why did people downvote the question? Einstein and Podolsky worked on more questions similar to my one. It is not just about entanglement.

You are likely confusing localized particles with the extended/delocalized wavefunctions they obey.

Usually, the counts would not be doubled.
The effective wave function of the particle collapses because the particle's wave function interacts with the macroscopic environment.
Let $\psi$ the state of the particle and $\Psi$ the state of the detectors. The time evolution would yield a superposition.
$$\Psi \otimes \psi \stackrel{\text{time}}\mapsto \frac{1}{N}[ \Psi_A \otimes \psi_A +  \Psi_B \otimes \psi_B]$$
where $\Psi_A$, $\Psi_B$ are the states in which either detector $A$ or $B$ has clicked.
According to the Kopenhagen view nature chooses one branch, either $\Psi_A \otimes \psi_A$ or $\Psi_B \otimes \psi_B$  and neglect the other.
Note that this process is not special to "detectors" set up by physicists but happens whenever a small system interacts with the enviroment.
Thus, also the wall of your lab or a beam dumb etc. could lead to a collapse of the conditional wave function.
If you remove one detector, a lot of particles will just stay undetected by the detectors you have placed.
Note, however, that under certain circumstances the presence of a detector can change interference patterns. For example a detector placed at one of the slits in a two slit experiment could change the pattern a detector aka. screen could detect behind the double slit.

If the two detectors are close to each other and one is removed, the other one should detect those particles. We know that one particle can not be detected by two detectors. If there is no increase in the particle count after A is removed, then something is wrong with quantum mechanics.

I have another remark. It follows from what you described that in your view the particle is localized. But, the wave function is an extended object. This is proven by the double slit experiment. Otherwise, the interference pattern would not be seen. This means that the wave function of "one" particle could reach both detectors in my experiment. In that case, the particle count should increase if one of the detectors is removed and they are close to each other because the wave function reaches both detectors A and B. This experiment could be a critical test of quantum mechanics.

@wawa when reading your question, I assumed the detectors would be on opposite ends. I think the person answering did the same. If you modify the detectors to be so close that the localized wavepacket has enough support for both of them, then yes, removing another interaction (the detector) will affect the results.

You are making the mistake of assuming there is something special about detectors. They are simply part of the wider environment in which the particles exist. There is a chance a particle might interact with one detector or another or not interact with either of them. If you remove one detector, you increase the proportion of particles that are undetected.
